# How to set up correctly avatar custom filter for users.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to set up custom filter for avatars in `users.php` in administration of WordPress. I checked if user has gravatar or uploaded own picture. I'm writing this information in to the separate column of users and also record it in to the database as `meta_key = 'avatar'` with value `Avatar` or `Gravatar`.

[image: avatar-filter-users-php]

I tried to implement it like is explained [here](https://www.intelliwolf.com/how-to-add-a-custom-filter-to-wordpress-users-list), but without success.

This is my function to show filter input with button at the top of the list of users.

```
function filter_by_avatar($which)
{
 // template for filtering
 $st = '<select name="avatar_%s" style="float:none;margin-left:10px;">
        <option value="">%s</option>%s</select>';

 // generate options
 $options = '<option value="avatar">Avatar</option>
             <option value="gravatar">Gravatar</option>';

 // combine template and options
 $select = sprintf( $st, $which, __( 'Type of avatar...' ), $options );

 // output <select> and submit button
 echo $select;
 submit_button(__( 'Filter' ), null, $which, false);
}

add_action('restrict_manage_users', 'filter_by_avatar');
```

And this is `filter` function:

```
function filter_users_by_avatar_section($query)
{
    global $pagenow;
    if (is_admin() && 'users.php' == $pagenow) {
            // put the filtering code in here
        //$top = $_GET['avatar_top'];
        $top = $_GET['avatar_avatar'];
        //$bottom = $_GET['avatar_bottom'];
        $bottom = $_GET['avatar_gravatar'];
        if (!empty($top) OR !empty($bottom))
        {
            $section = !empty($top) ? $top : $bottom;

            $meta_query = array (array (
                'key' => 'avatar',
                'value' => $section,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ));
            $query->set('meta_key', 'avatar');
            $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
        }
    }
}
```

When I choose from dropdown Avatar of Gravatar and click Filter, result is only refreshing the page.